# Setting a title for every page PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to use the constructor to put a title on every page unless I specify what the title should be for the specific page...

For the How it Works page.. the title should be "TeamPlayer - How it works!" (Which currently works)
For the FAQ page the title should be "TeamPlayer" (Which currently doesn't work).

I don't want to have to put the $data['title'] = 'TeamPlayer'; in every function. How do I fix my problem?

```
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $data['title'] = 'TeamPlayer';
    }

public function howitworks()
{
        $data['title'] = 'TeamPlayer - How it works!';
        load_page('howitworks', $data);
}

    public function faq()
{
        load_page('faq', $data);

}
```

EDIT:::

I don't understand how I can be more descriptive in my problem.. To help those trying to help... Here is how I am echoing my titles in my views. I tried using some of the solutions provided but could not get them to function within my controllers

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Comment: Where is `$data` coming from?

Comment: Probably this information is of use to you: [When Flat PHP meets Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html) - It contains a section how to have default page data like the title and the option for the pages to set their own title and add own information as well.

Comment: Object constructors don't magically set page titles in HTML output. You're using some framework, and have neglected to inform us about it.

Comment: You want to make the title optional. What about not needing to call `load_page()` in every page function?

Comment: In my view I put the following code

    <title><?php if (isset ($title)) echo $title; else {echo "TeamPlayer";}?></title>

This way I didn't need to try to mess with the constructor. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Rather then create a function to for each title why not use one function to set the title:

```
private $title;

public function setTitle($title) {
    $this->title = $title;
}
```

so inside your howitworks function you can set the title

```
public function howitworks()
{
        $this->setTitle('TeamPlayer - How it works!');
        load_page('howitworks', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function __construct($title=NULL)    {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($title===NULL)
            $data['title'] = 'TeamPlayer';
}
```

Comment: what if $title is not NULL? :)

Comment: Dunno how/where he passes his array `$data`. My example is just an idea for him.

Comment: I think this is unclear until we have sorted out what the OP actually is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution isn't really flexible. What if you want to further specialize those pages (think about tags for SEO, extra elements for navigation panels and all that stuff...).

Create sub-classes for each page, which (among other things) will update the title. Then load_page could instantiate the appropriate class.